# Invisible non-whitespace character to force Discord bot to output emotes in miniature form?

Tags: python, discord.py

The following is a chunk of code for my Discord bot:

```
mus = character_mus[arg]
        mu_strs = []
        chars_used = 0
        for i in mus:
            if len(mus[i]) == 0:
                continue
            s = ""
            s += (i + ": ")
            for char in mus[i]:
                if len(s + characters[char]) >= 2000:
                    mu_strs.append(s)
                    s=""
                s += (characters[char] + " ")
            s = s[0:len(s)-1] + ","
            mu_strs.append(s)
        time_str = most_recent.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Implemented is a way to break up long lines of emotes in order to abide by Discord's 2000-character limit. However, smaller lines with only emotes will display them in regular size, which looks really awkward when juxtaposed with the other lines.
[output without end character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONLQ5.png).

The following line tries to deal with this:
`s = s[0:len(s)-1] + ","`
It works, but the output is still kind of ugly:
[output without end character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSgsZ.png).
Is there a workaround such that the end character isn't visible to the user?

Comment: You can use the `replace` method on strings and remove the `,` character if I understood you correctly.

Comment: may you elaborate?

Comment: If you want to remove the `,` character at the end, check out the `replace` method, which is pretty good explained in the following [example](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp#:~:text=The%20replace()%20method%20replaces,if%20nothing%20else%20is%20specified). In your code, if you append things as a string, you could try to do `.replace(',', '')` when you output them.